# Tool to resolve multiple merge conflicts in git using either "mine" or "theirs"

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I have a situation where I am merging down changesets that have mutliple binary files in git.  It is always the case where I will resolve the changes using either "Mine" or "Theirs".  I have been using TortoiseGit for most of my day-to-day operations, but the merge conflict dialog, while allowing for multi-select, does not allow for multiple "resolve using theirs".  It only ever resolves one file at a time.

Is there a tool that I could use for this specific situation (select 100+ files and resolve using theirs)?

Comment: Since, for binary files, you're presumably taking the *entire file* (rather than selected sections) you can simply run `git checkout MERGE_HEAD -- path1 path2 ... pathN` from the command line.  Not quite what you wanted, it's not a GUI... :-)

Comment: And typing all those paths would take just as long as resolving them one by one using tortoisegit.

Comment: Not necessarily. If you can create a find expression, it may be as easy as `find <your expression> -print0 | xargs -0 git checkout MERGE_HEAD --`.

Comment: Thought of reporting about to tortoisegit? https://tortoisegit.org/issues

Comment: The issue has already been reported with TortoiseGit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to use the `git` command line program, you can specify the `ours` or `theirs` option to the `recursive` merge strategy to resolve **all** conflicts by selecting "our" changes or "their" changes, respectively.

```
git merge -s recursive -X ours other-branch
# or
git merge -s recursive -X theirs other-branch
```

(The `recursive` merge strategy is the default, so you probably don't have to include `-s recursive`; it is included above for completeness.)

The full explanation is found in the [`git-merge` documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge.html#_merge_strategies):

> The *recursive* strategy can take the following options:
>
> **ours**
>
> This option forces conflicting hunks to be auto-resolved cleanly by favoring *our* version. Changes from the other tree that do not
>   conflict with our side are reflected to the merge result. For a binary
>   file, the entire contents are taken from our side.
>
> This should not be confused with the *ours* merge strategy, which does not even look at what the other tree contains at all. It discards
>   everything the other tree did, declaring *our* history contains all that
>   happened in it.
>
> **theirs**
>
> This is the opposite of *ours*.

Answer (score 1):

**Graphical Illusion**

In fact, I've experienced the same problem in **TortoiseGit**. It seems to be more a **cache glitch** than a real bug. The conflicts still appear in the conflict window however on the disk they are resolved.

In order to update the conflict window, just **kill the TortoiseGitCache.exe** that's running somewhere on your computer and next time you check your conflicts : *Tada!*

*Version checked: 1.8.16.0 (Windows 8.1 / 64 bit)*

***Note:*** You will face the same problem if you resolve directly in git command line and then check with Tortoise because of the cache.